# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA and SUMIF combination

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I recently noticed a mistake in my calculation, and I've identified the root cause of the problem: it seems that I mistakenly used the SUMIF function in Google Sheets' ARRAYFORMULA.

I have the sample spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e8GWjKzClMlFrGCv3DspZehXvbFXlgq_l34f582aGDY/edit?usp=sharing).

I wrote the `ARRAYFORMULA` function that results in column C, which I thought would be the same with the formula in column B.

The formula in column C:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(H$3:H$6&I$3:I$6,"<="&A3:A31&">="&A3:A31,G$3:G$6))
```

The formula in column B:

```
=SUMIFS(G$3:G$6,H$3:H$6,"<="&A3,I$3:I$6,">="&A3)
```

In essence, I want to get the value for each date based on predefined values with their own periods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use this formula in the cell C3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF((A3:A31>=TRANSPOSE(H3:H5))*
(A3:A31<=TRANSPOSE(I3:I5))=1,TRANSPOSE(G3:G5),0),ROW(G3:G5)^0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a new tab called MK.Help and erased all the other formulas.  then i put this formula in C3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(MMULT(N(A3:A>=TRANSPOSE(A3:A)),MMULT((A3:A>=TRANSPOSE(H3:H))*(A3:A<=TRANSPOSE(I3:I)),N(G3:G))),COUNTA(A3:A),1))
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: This is not the answer to my original question, but it answers the question I was about to ask here on Stackoverflow! You just answered a question even before I ask it, awesome!